# Tcl/Tk - how to get the prompt after executing an command using eval?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

The code to reproduce my problem is given below. I named the file as `test.tcl`

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
# test.tcl
#-------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace eval Gui {
}

proc Gui::test {} {
  toplevel .test
  wm title .test "Test"
  wm resizable .test 0 0 ;# not resizable

  # create a frame to hold the check widgets
  set f [frame .test.boolean -borderwidth 10] 
  pack $f -side top

  # OK and Cancel buttons
  button .test.ok -text "OK" -command [list Gui::Ok .test ]
  button .test.cancel -text "Cancel" -command [list Gui::cancel .test ]
  pack   .test.cancel .test.ok -side right

  bind .test <Return> {Gui::Ok .test ; break}
  bind .test <Escape> {Gui::cancel .test ; break}
}

proc Gui::Ok { arg } {
  set x [list puts "hello world!"]
  eval $x
  destroy $arg
}

proc Gui::cancel { arg } {
  destroy $arg
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------------
# Gui main window 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
proc Gui::initialize { } {

  # build the frame which contains menu options
  frame .mbar -relief raised -bd 2
  frame .mdummy -width 200 -height 240
  pack .mbar .mdummy -side top -fill x

  # menu options
  menubutton .mbar.command -text Command -underline 0 -menu .mbar.command.menu
  pack .mbar.command -side left

  # menu under command options
  menu .mbar.command.menu -tearoff 0
  .mbar.command.menu add command -label "Test..." -command [list Gui::test]
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------------
# main code
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
Gui::initialize
```

When I type

```
% wish
% source test.tcl
%
```

and then I click `Command -> Test ... -> OK` which gives me

```
% hello world!
```

I don't get the prompt `%` back after it prints `hello world!`. Though I can still execute tcl commands in that space. For example:

```
% hello world!
puts "hi"
hi
%
```

which returns the prompt.

*My question*: 
How to get the prompt `%` back after tcl/tk executes the `eval` command which prints `hello world!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prompt `%` came from tcl interpreter and shown in the terminal just because it's in interactive mode. If you run your script as `wish test.tcl` you will never get `%`.

You can implement your own interactive mode and call it after all initialization steps of your app. Here the example how it can be done:

```
proc Gui::interactive {} {
  set prompt1 "tcl>"
  set prompt2 "?"
  set cmd {}
  set prompt "$prompt1 "
  fconfigure stdin -blocking false -buffering line
  fileevent stdin readable {set Gui::stdinReady 1}
  while true {
    puts -nonewline $prompt
    flush stdout
    vwait Gui::stdinReady
    set str [gets stdin]
    lappend cmd $str
    set cmdStr [join $cmd "\n"]
    if {[info complete $cmdStr]} {
      set cmd {}
      if {$cmdStr != ""} {
        if {[catch {eval $cmdStr} result]} {
          puts stderr "ERROR: $result"
        } elseif {$result != ""} {
          puts $result
        }
      }
      set prompt "$prompt1 "
    } else {
      set prompt "$prompt2 "
    }
    if {[eof stdin]} {
      puts ""
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Just call this function after `Gui::test` execution and you;ll get your own prompt.
But even with this example the prompt will not be redrawn if a text will be printed to the terminal from some other procedure.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out and let you know

Comment: I was able to call Gui::interactive from Gui::test and when I execute `Command -> Test ... -> OK` the prompt appears as `tcl>`; 

But when I type something in tclsh I get the prompt `% tcl>` 

Any suggestion to get rid of the extra `%` in `% tcl>`?

Comment: Just do not execute tcl in interactive mode. Run as `wish your_script.tcl`.

Answer (score 3):

You never lost the `%` prompt.  Here's what's happening:

You have a prompt:

`%`

Then you print a string on that same line:

`% hello world!`

Your "current" prompt is still that same thing. The following command is "on" that prompt:

`puts "hi"`

Which, because it is running in tclsh and because you just inserted a newline, comes on the next line:

`hi`

And you get another prompt:

`%`

You didn't get "another" prompt from your GUI thing because `puts "hello world"` wasn't processed by tclsh directly. Basically, as far as tclsh is concerned, the "hello world" came from Mars and screwed up your terminal. It doesn't even know that is there.

Maybe a better way to explain it is this: If your `puts "hello world"` was printing to a *file*, then you would still have your `%` prompt. But someone took those characters and shoved them onto your display (including the newline).

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way to communicate with the tclsh directly?

Comment: I can't think of a way to "refresh" the terminal screen from the program, no. But why do you have to work in tclsh directly anyway?

Comment: +1 for a good explanation. Tclsh doesn't do special binding to the terminal, so detecting things like a Ctrl+R (the traditional terminal refresh sequence) doesn't happen and the prompt remains unprinted. You could always try using tkcon as an alternative, but that's a *very* different approach (graphical application doing some terminal emulation, not full terminal handling).

Comment: I am developing an application in which the user can use both tclsh and gui and also mix them; thats the reason why I need the prompt back.

Comment: Then I think you want GrAnd's idea of implementing your own tclsh shell that can be aware of when you've printed results from the GUI. Alternatively, you can print GUI results elsewhere.